# In what kind of cases do we use TriG syntax?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, turtle-rdf

What are the practical uses cases of [TriG](https://www.w3.org/TR/trig/) for stating RDF data? And why is it important?
I did read this from the W3C

> A TriG document allows writing down an RDF Dataset in a compact textual form. It consists of a sequence of directives, triple statements, graph statements which contain triple-generating statements and optional blank lines. Comments may be given after a # that is not part of another lexical token and continue to the end of the line.
> Graph statements are a pair of an IRI or blank node label and a group of triple statements surrounded by {}. The IRI or blank node label of the graph statement may be used in another graph statement which implies taking the union of the tripes generated by each graph statement. An IRI or blank node label used as a graph label may also reoccur as part of any triple statement. Optionally a graph statement may not not be labeled with an IRI. Such a graph statement corresponds to the Default Graph of an RDF Dataset.

But what kind of use case needs "writing down an RDF Dataset in a compact textual form?"
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A dataset consists of many graphs. Turtle can be used for a single graph, while TriG can be used to express multiple graphs in a single file. Its advantages for expressing RDF are otherwise comparable to Turtle, so you'd only consider using it over Turtle when you have multiple graphs to encode.